# Line using a brush in Illustrator not showing coloured arrowheads

Tags: adobe-illustrator

**I am trying to draw a line with an arrowhead, all in the selected Stroke Colour.**

I want to use a particular Brush for the line. The brush is set to Hue Colourisation, so I can determine the colour of the line (even while using the brush) just by setting the Stroke Colour.

However, the moment I use this Brush, the arrowhead reverts to black. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out. The brush applied to the line was Hue Colourising on a colour other than black. Therefore the black arrowhead was not also taking on the hue.

To use a Brush together with an Arrowhead, all to be shown in the Stroke Colour, the Brush must be Hue Colourised using a Black spot colour.